# Sync android map with a SQLite database on a server

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-maps

I created an SQLite database for my android map application that keeps user's favorite markers using [this tutorial](https://github.com/javierchavez/youtube-maps),

now I want to create another same database that allows users to share some markers with others who uses this app, so I need to upload my database on a server and sync it with my app and restore shared markers.

which server can I use that keeps my database in SQL not in JSON.
how can I sync my app with my uploaded database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to talk directly to your remote database, because you have to store the authentication credentials inside the app and its pretty easy to reverse engineer your app and get this credentials.

I would recommend you to write a small service/API with 2 endpoints. One endpoint to get all the markers available and the other one to store the markers.

The communication with your API you can handle with e.g. [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). You store the markers via your `POST` call. With the `GET` call you get all the markers available in the database. Then you can store the response got from the call inside the users local database.

**UPDATE:**

[REST API with NodeJS and MongoDB](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/08/restful-api-node-mongodb/)

[Retrofit Tutorial](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-retrofit-2/)

Comment: can you give me a tutorial link about this stuff? a tutorial like for dummies! I am really really new in this stuff

Comment: I added 2 links with tutorials. If the answer and the tutorials were helpful feel free to mark the answer as correct ;)

Comment: I was reading those links and I have some questions about retrofit, can you help or I have to post another question?

Comment: I would recommend to write a new post or search for similar questions. There are a lot of Q&As about retrofit on stackoverflow

Comment: sorry I have one more question about this subject, are these the steps for my purpose?  saving markers in SQLite and convert it to json then using retrofit for get the markers back from json to my app?